# How to access an object inside an Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

I have a bunch of objects in an Array.

- How can I access the objects?
- And how to add a key to every object?

**Example**

```
var gradesArr = [
    {
        'name' : 'Пешо',
        'score' : 91
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Лилия',
        'score' : 290
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Алекс',
        'score' : 343,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Габриела',
        'score' : 400
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Жичка',
        'score' : 70
    }]
```

I want to add a key `hasPassed` to the objects, which have a score over 100.

But I can't mind of a way to do this.

Comment: that's not json. that's javascript... you access it like you would any other object-in-array: `gradesArr[1]['score']` -> `290`.

Comment: You seem to have regular JS objects, the question has nothing to do with JSON. Something to read: [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and finally: [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON).

Comment: Thank you.Idk why but I left with the idea that JSON is a regular object in JavaScript.And if you read the title you wouldn't have tell me that this is js ;d But nevertheless thank you ! I will try this out. And I actually need an " if " for all the objects.Regards

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format, it's not a JS object. JSON object is a built-in object in JS engines, the one having `parse` and `stringify` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the Array and add a property to those objects. E.g:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gradesArr.length; i++) {
  if (gradesArr[i].score > 100) {
    gradesArr[i].hasPassed = true;
  }
}
```

```js
var gradesArr = [{
  'name': 'Пешо',
  'score': 91
}, {
  'name': 'Лилия',
  'score': 290
}, {
  'name': 'Алекс',
  'score': 343,
}, {
  'name': 'Габриела',
  'score': 400
}, {
  'name': 'Жичка',
  'score': 70
}];


for (var i = 0; i < gradesArr.length; i++) {
  if (gradesArr[i].score > 100) {
    gradesArr[i].hasPassed = true;
  }
}

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(gradesArr, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Use Object.keys or hasOwnProperty to limit the property lookup to the object itself.

Comment: @flackoDev if my answer was useful for you, please mark it as accepted, by clicking on the `V` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `forEach` method of arrays to apply the desired changes.

```js
var gradesArr = [{
  'name': 'Пешо',
  'score': 91
}, {
  'name': 'Лилия',
  'score': 290
}, {
  'name': 'Алекс',
  'score': 343,
}, {
  'name': 'Габриела',
  'score': 400
}, {
  'name': 'Жичка',
  'score': 70
}];

gradesArr.forEach(function(person) {
  if (person.score > 100) {
    person.hasPassed = true;
  }
});

document.getElementById("my_out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(gradesArr);
```

```html
<div id="my_out"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to use a prototype's method to do that, you should be using `forEach`, because `map` has nothing to do with that (although, it will obviously work), since its purpose is to map all the items of an array, and return a new array with the converted items.

Comment: @Buzinas You are right, thank you for the correction.